# Newbie Q: Is "Field Level Security" the same as "Field Accessibility"?

Tags: security, field-level-security

There are two buttons that seem very similar when viewing the detial page for an object: <kbd>Set Field Level Security</kbd> and <kbd>View Field Accessibility</kbd>. They both seem to allow you to set the field level security.

Are these ("Field Level Security" and "Field Accessibility") basically the same thing?

Comment: Field Level Security is a subset of Field Accessibility

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can modify `Field Level Security` from the `Field Accessibility` screen, but it's not the only thing you can modify.

From [Modifying Field Access Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=modifying_field_access_settings.htm&language=en):

> From the field accessibility grid, you can click any field access setting to change the field’s accessibility in the page layout or in field-level security. The Access Settings page then lets you modify the field access settings.
>
> - In the Field-Level Security section of the page, specify the field's access level for the profile.
>
> ```
> Access Level                              Enabled Settings
> Users can read and edit the field.        Visible
> Users can read but not edit the field.    Visible and Read-Only
> Users can’t read or edit the field.       None
> ```
>
> We recommend that you use field-level security to control users’ access to fields rather than creating multiple page layouts to control field access.
>
> - In the Page Layout section of the page, you can:
>
>   - Select the `Remove or change editability` radio button and then change the field access properties for the page layout. These changes will affect all profile and record type combinations that currently use this page layout.
>   - Alternatively, you can select the `Choose a different page layout` radio button to assign a different page layout to the profile and record type combination.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a noob, and just getting a handle on security. Here's what I just learned:

- We're talking about object (not record) level access
- It starts with Profile object permissions
- That can get expanded (opening up access) with Permission Set object permissions
- Then that gets narrowed (closing down access) with Field Permissions
- Field Permissions can't give you access denied by Profile object permissions + Permission Set object permissions
- You can set Field Permissions in 2 places: in the Profile interface, and from the field list of an object
- The 2 different interfaces use DIFFERENT names for the settings (very confusing!)
- Layouts will automatically adapt to however you change these settings
- To matters more twisted, Permission Sets (expanding access) can contain Field Permissions (restricting access)

If I'm getting this wrong I'd sure like to hear about it.  Hope it helps.

Mark